# Выбор элемента в списке по определенной логике

Tags: python

Напиши функцию которая принимает строку, которая представляет собой URL страницы этого товара в Интернет-магазине и возвращает идентификатор товара из строки.
Идентификатор это первое число после символа р (символов р может быть несколько в строке).

Написал код но не получается взять следующее число, после p.

```
def get_product_id(url: str) -> str:
    new = url.split('-')
    for i in new:
        if i == 'p':
            if (i+1).isdigit():
                s = new.remove(i+1)
    return s
```

Для проверки использую вот такие URL адреса:

```
print(get_product_id("exampleshop.com/dry-water-just-add-water-to-get-water-p-147-24122017.html"))  # 147
print(get_product_id("exampleshop.com/fancy-coffee-cup-p-90764-12052019.html"))  # "90764"
print(get_product_id("exampleshop.com/public-toilet-proximity-radar-p-942312798-01012020.html"))  # "942312798"
print(get_product_id("exampleshop.com/best-hotel-123123-p-321321-01012020.html"))  # "321321"
print(get_product_id("exampleshop.com/a-have-a-lot-of-p-in-my-url-p-007-01012020.html"))  # 007
```

Comment: Решил сам ``` def get_product_id(url: str) -> str:
    new = url.split('-')
    for i in range(1, len(new)-1):
        if new[i] == 'p':
            if (new[i+1]).isdigit():
                d = new[i+1]
                return d```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_product_id(url: str) -> str:
    new = url.split('-')
    for i in range(len(new)-1):
        if new[i] == 'p':
            if new[i+1].isdigit():
                s = new[i+1]
    return s
```

Доделал именно вашу функцию, вы использовали `for i in new`, это значит что `i` будет элементом массива, в моей реализации `i` это именно индекс элемента. Тогда чтобы обратиться к элементу мы используем `new[i]`. Также стоит заметить, что метод `new.remove()` ничего не возвращает, а лишь удаляет элемент из списка, поэтому я заменил эту строчку простым присваиванием. Ещё стоит обратить внимание на то, чтобы не выйти за пределы массива, мы используем `len(new)-1`, так как у нас есть `new[i+1]`. (это сделано на тот случай, если "p" окажется последним элементом в массиве)